# I'm Trying to Get Keras to Load vgg16.h5 Wheights Locally Instead of Downloading

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I've tried modifying this code serveral different ways,
from trying to change the last lines to my vgg16.h5 file on my local disk,
to importing load_weights from Keras and trying to get it to grab the weights that way instead.

This code is from lesson 1 of the fast.ai course. I've asked on their forum but got no response.

The files running this are in this link.
https://github.com/fastai/courses/tree/master/deeplearning1/nbs
lesson1.ipynb calls on the file vgg16.py to download the weights.
The code below starts at line 117 in the vgg16.py file.

```
def create(self):
    """
        Creates the VGG16 network achitecture and loads the pretrained weights.
        Args:   None
        Returns:   None
    """
    model = self.model = Sequential()
    model.add(Lambda(vgg_preprocess, input_shape=(3,224,224), output_shape=(3,224,224)))

    self.ConvBlock(2, 64)
    self.ConvBlock(2, 128)
    self.ConvBlock(3, 256)
    self.ConvBlock(3, 512)
    self.ConvBlock(3, 512)

    model.add(Flatten())
    self.FCBlock()
    self.FCBlock()
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))

    fname = 'vgg16.h5'
    model.load_weights(get_file(fname, self.FILE_PATH+fname, cache_subdir='models'))
```

The above code is the code out of the box that downloads the weights.
When I change that last line and get rid of everything in the parenthesis except for 'fname' like this...

```
    fname = 'vgg16.h5'  
    model.load_weights(fname)
```

I get the error below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2b6861506a11> in <module>()
----> 1 vgg = Vgg16()
      2 # Grab a few images at a time for training and validation.
      3 # NB: They must be in subdirectories named based on their category
      4 batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'train', batch_size=batch_size)
      5 val_batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'valid', batch_size=batch_size*2)

/home/eagle/fastai/courses-master/deeplearning1/nbs/vgg16.pyc in __init__(self)
     45     def __init__(self):
     46         self.FILE_PATH = 'http://files.fast.ai/models/'
---> 47         self.create()
     48         self.get_classes()
     49 

/home/eagle/fastai/courses-master/deeplearning1/nbs/vgg16.pyc in create(self)
    137 
    138         fname = 'vgg16.h5'
--> 139         model.load_weights(fname)
    140 
    141 

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/topology.pyc in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name)
   2706             self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f)
   2707         else:
-> 2708             self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f)
   2709 
   2710         if hasattr(f, 'close'):

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/topology.pyc in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(self, f)
   2792                         weight_values[0] = w
   2793                 weight_value_tuples += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)
-> 2794             K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
   2795 
   2796     def load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(self, f):

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in batch_set_value(tuples)
   1879             assign_ops.append(assign_op)
   1880             feed_dict[assign_placeholder] = value
-> 1881         get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
   1882 
   1883 

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in get_session()
    120                 config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=nb_thread,
    121                                         allow_soft_placement=True)
--> 122             _SESSION = tf.Session(config=config)
    123         session = _SESSION
    124     if not _MANUAL_VAR_INIT:

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
   1191 
   1192     """
-> 1193     super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
   1194     # NOTE(mrry): Create these on first `__enter__` to avoid a reference cycle.
   1195     self._default_graph_context_manager = None

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
    552     try:
    553       with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
--> 554         self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
    555     finally:
    556       tf_session.TF_DeleteSessionOptions(opts)

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/contextlib.pyc in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     22         if type is None:
     23             try:
---> 24                 self.gen.next()
     25             except StopIteration:
     26                 return
/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.pyc in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    464           None, None,
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:
    468     pywrap_tensorflow.TF_DeleteStatus(status)

InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

Comment: Why the thumbs down? There are no clear instructions for modifying Keras code to make it grab the weights locally instead of downloading online or asked on this site. This is an actual, real problem I'm having and this is a site for answering questions, not exercising judgement over what you, as a pretend authority deem as a stupid question.

Comment: (Don't use that tone of voice, it may get you banned from asking any further questions, for a short or longer while or forever.) I don't know about the downvote but you don't say how your current code fails. FWIW it appears to me it should work.

Comment: Oh wait. `get_file` is *specifically* to "download a file from a URL if it not already in the cache". Just give it your file name and don't use that function, perhaps?

Comment: Not to disagree with you but everything I tried failed in different ways. I'll post one. I feel like I put the crux of the issue out here on this site a lot and I'm made to feel like an a-hole for asking because I didn't follow some technicality. The code as I posted "works" at starting to download the weights from a website even though the weights are in my env's root directory.

Comment: So that function indeed does what it says in the documentation, and not what you intend to. Yes – include your attempt, please. Explain what part specifically failed, if possible.

Comment: I put one error up there. When instead of using the 'fname' variable for vgg16.h5 and just put /path/to/file/vgg16.h5 alone in load_weights() instead I get another long error that says my path to the file is not a valid URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the folder Keras is/ or would store this weight file and dropped it in there with the following line in Terminal.

```
mv /home/mine/fastai/courses-master/deeplearning1/nbs/vgg16.h5 ~/.keras/models/vgg16.h5
```

The first path is the path with my fully downloaded weights .h5 file. The second path is where I put said weights and the path Keras looks at to find the weights.

Answer (score 4):

One of the possible ways to load weights locally is as follows:

```
vgg = vgg16.VGG16(weights=<path_to_weights_file>)
```

This will work fine. And there is no need to modify the vgg16.py file at all.

Answer (score 3):

Copying the `.h5` file to `.keras/models/` and modifying the `vgg16.py` at line 30 to

`WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP = ('.keras/models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')` seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

The path in different system:
Linux:

```
~/.keras/models/
```

Win:

```
settings/.keras/models/ of Python
```

Anaconda on Win

```
D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\keras\api\keras\applications\vgg16
```

Putting the downloaded .h5 file to these local folder seems to work.